# How to change multiple queries to a single query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have three tables namely "Projects", "Platforms", "Details".

I have collected detail from the Projects table, then Platforms table and Details table. From the details table we may get the multiple values or single value.

I have written the Linq query like below:

```
using (PEntities CSProject = new PEntities())
{
    projectId =    (from _project in CSProject.Projects
                    where _project.ProjectName == project
                    select _project.ProjectId).SingleOrDefault();

    platformId =   (from platformID in CSProject.Projects
                    where platformID.ProjectName == project
                    select platformID.PlatformId).SingleOrDefault();

    platformName = (from platfrmName in CSProject.Platforms
                    where platfrmName.PlatformId == platformId
                    select platfrmName.PlatformName).SingleOrDefault();

    cSProjectId =  (from _csproject in CSProject.Details
                    where _csproject.ProjectId == projectId
                    select _csproject.CsprojectId).ToList<long?>();
}
```

Can you please help me out to write the above all query in a single single line?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) for each of the values that you want to get in the `select` statement, like so (in SQL):

```
select
    (select ProjectId from Projects where ProjectName = @project) as ProjectId,
    (select PlatformId from Projects where ProjectName = @project) as PlatformId,
    ...
```

In SQL, the above doesn't need a table to query against (it will return one row), but you'll need something in LINQ-to-Entities, which will force you to query against a context, make sure there is at least one value in the table, etc.

Needless to say, it's not worth it, and while you'll gain less calls to the database, the actual query that is sent will be *very* complex.

That said, you're better off doing one of two things.  The first is to create a stored procedure that creates the correlated subqueries and returns one record like above and call that from LINQ-to-Entities.

The other, if you are really looking for one *record* that stores these values is to store them in a type.  Here's how to do it in an anonymous type:

```
using (PEntities CSProject = new PEntities())
{
    var results = new {
        ProjectId = (
            from _project in CSProject.Projects
            where _project.ProjectName == project
            select _project.ProjectId).SingleOrDefault(),

        PlatformId = (
            from platformID in CSProject.Projects
            where platformID.ProjectName == project
            select platformID.PlatformId).SingleOrDefault(),

        PlatformName = (
            from platfrmName in CSProject.Platforms
            where platfrmName.PlatformId == platformId
            select platfrmName.PlatformName).SingleOrDefault();

        CsProjectId = (
            from _csproject in CSProject.Details
            where _csproject.ProjectId == projectId
            select _csproject.CsprojectId).ToList<long?>();
    };
}
```

You won't see a reduction in calls to the database, but if what you're going for is a single record with these values, then this will achieve it.